# How to compare single string chars in C++?

Tags: c++

I wanted to compare two single string variable in my SC and if they were different, I wanted to add +1 to my int data "fights", let's say *X[1] = A, Y[1] = B, add +1 to **fights***.

```
    int N;
    char X;
    char Y;

    int fights = 0;

    1 <= N <= 100000;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cin >> X[i];
        cin >> Y[i];

        if (Y[i] != X[i]){
           fights += 1;
        }     
    }
    cout << fights;

    return 0;
}
```

However, it seems like the program is not detecting any differences when I input different letters and does not add +1 to ***fights***.

Comment: X & Y are not arrays, and you're not checking if your input succeeds. Perhaps you'd like to supply an example that compiles? https://ideone.com/eHdZ5s

Comment: I probably was unable to define the exact number of N by including `cin >> N;` to my SC. Probably the reason why it does not add +1 to my **int fights**.

Comment: What happens when you try to access a char like a pointer or array by using the subscript operator? Say the first element [0]? Is it just a simple dereference?

Comment: `N` has not been initialized, so pretty much anything you do with it will produce undefined behavior. In particular, `1 <= N <= 100000;` does not do anything.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are not declaring variables X and Y as array but then using it like one which will give error! u will first have to specify it only then it can be used !

```
  #include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
 int main(){

int N;
    char X[10]; //specify any size according to ur need 
    char Y[10]; // but size specification of array is compulsary

    int fights = 0;

    // 1 <= N <= 100000;         <-- i dont think this is required
    // just use a no. for conditional expression in for 
    // here there is no need for comparing it with other variable
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cin >> X; 
        cin >> Y;


        if (strcmp(X,Y)==0){
           fights += 1;
        }     
    }
    cout << fights;

    return 0;
}
```

here u can enter a 10 character input in both the variables(you can change it according to ur need) if both have exact same characters it will add nothing to fights other wise 1 will be added!

Comment: It did helped me somehow but when I'm dealing with longer char inputs, like `ABCD` for `X[i]` and `ACBE` for `Y[i]`, it's adding twice more in **fights** rather than adding only +1 in every different letter, like if `X[2] != Y[2], +1 fights` and so on. Am I missing something else?

Comment: wait i will edit my answer for what you seek!

Comment: this should solve ur problem!

Comment: Thanks for the help though I am actually more concerned about the number of differences of the characters inputted by the user(assuming they are of equal length). Let's say I input `ABC` for `X` and `CBA` for `Y`. Since `X[1] = A ; Y[1] = C`; `X[3] = C ; Y[3] = A` which are different, `int fights` is expected to return a value of 2.

Comment: ok i am working on it!

Comment: Re: "I dont think this is required" -- how diplomatic! That bit of code is meaningless.

Comment: well didnt wanted to be rude or so!

Comment: that piece of code !

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

 int main(){


    char X[10]; 
    char Y[10]; 
    int n;
    int fights = 0;
    cin >> X; 
    cin >> Y;
    if(strlen(X) > strlen(Y))
         n = strlen(X);
    else
       n = strlen(Y);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(X[i]!=Y[i]) {
            fights +=1;
        }
      else 
        ;     
     }
    cout << fights;

    return 0;
}
```

this will do the comparing properly !

Answer (score -2):

Change X,Y to an array.

Working Code :

```
int N;
char X[100001];   
char Y[100001];

int fights = 0;

1 <= N <= 100000;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    cin >> X[i];
    cin >> Y[i];

    if (Y[i] != X[i]){
       fights += 1;
    }     
}
cout << fights;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Makes sense to me. What's the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I have no idea what is the reason for down vote.

Comment: Not asking you. I'm asking the (potential) downvoters.

Comment: I also want to know the same thing.

Comment: -1: `N` has not been initialized (`1 <= N <= 100000;` does nothing), so its use as a loop limit means that the behavior of the code is undefined.

Comment: This is most definitely not working code